# Find controller name inside view in Padrino

Tags: padrino

How can I access the controller name inside a partial or a view thats rendered by the controller.

I want to create a dynamic template that changes depending on the controller rendering it, whats the best way to do it? I would prefer to access the controller inside the view rather than setting a new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to detect the entry point in Padrino: request.controller and request.action.

```
controller :foo do
  get :bar do
    [request.controller, request.action].inspect
  end
end

=> ["foo", :bar]
```